# how to solve error Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
hey sorry for the bad english i hope you guys understand what i mean.i have this code below but i get error "Type 'Blob | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.
```

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'.",do you guys know how to solve this error and please do tell me in detail what need to change or add because i am really new to typescript

[image: error]

```
 const showCroppedImage = useCallback(async () => {
            try {
              const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(inputImg, croppedAreaPixels);
              onCropImage(
                new File([croppedImage], imgName, {
                  type: "image/png",
                  lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
                })
              );
            } catch (e) {
              console.error(e);
            }
            
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your functions, you can probably do this:

```
 const showCroppedImage = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(inputImg, croppedAreaPixels);

    // add this
    if (!croppedImage) {
      return;
    }

    onCropImage(
      new File([croppedImage], imgName, {
        type: "image/png",
        lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
      })
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

The early return guards against `croppedImage` not being defined. Alternatively you can rewrite `getCroppedImg` to always return a value.